# How do I find the common ratio of .$\dots ,4, \text{ __ }, \text{ __ },108$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, ratio, geometric-series

How can I find the common ratio of $\dots ,4, \text{ __ }, \text{ __ },108$? And find the missing terms? I tried doing  it and I got $3$ for the common ration but for some reason my friend said my common ration was wrong, so please can anybody help me?

Comment: $3$ is correct.

Comment: There are two complex numbers it could be, because 27 has three cube roots.

Comment: @Empy2 if it were implied that the sequence was specifically consisting only of real numbers then we can rule those other roots out.

Comment: But the friend might be thinking of this.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I think the idea is you have 4 elements with common ratio: $4,x,y,108$. Let's say the common ratio is $r$. Then, $x = 4r$ and $y = xr = (4r)\cdot r = 4r^2$. Can you express $108$ in terms of $r$ and solve to find $r$?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Consider
$$
2^2, 3\cdot 2^2, 3^2\cdot 2^2,3^3\cdot 2^2.
$$